# Проверка на наличие объекта в базе данных

Tags: java, hibernate

Как оптимальнее проверить при сохранении - есть ли уже объект в базе данных? Подойдет ли код:

```
session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("select name from User where name = :userName");
query.setParameter("userName", user.getName());         

if (((org.hibernate.query.Query) query).list().isEmpty()) {
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Вполне оптимальный вариант, особенно если в БД по полю `name` есть индекс. Можно добавить ограничение количества выбираемых записей: maxResults = 1. Но есть проблема с транзакцией - она начинается всегда, а завершается только если вошли в блок `if`. Если новая запись не будет добавлена - состояние транзакции останется неопределённым. Следует перенести `session.beginTransaction()` в начало блока `if`. А для осуществления выборки из БД (`select`) транзакция не нужна.

Comment: @bobzer, спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы немного по другому сделал бы:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select name from User where name = :userName");
query.setParameter("userName", user.getName());         

if (((org.hibernate.query.Query) query).list().isEmpty()) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Смысл в том, что незачем городить транзакцию при проверке наличия. Если нет то тогда только имеет смысл начинать транзакцию.

Транзакция достаточно дорогая штука и не фиг ее расходовать на тупую проверку.